# string comparison, return most similar

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, comparison

Search substrings from a string and get a substring that matches the most!

```
string [] allModels = { "Galaxy", "S3", "Galaxy S3" };
string title = "Samasung galaxy s3 is for sale";
string[] title_array = title.Split(' ');
string model = "";
foreach(var tit in title_array)
{
      foreach(var mod in allModels)
      {
             if (mod.Equals(tit, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
             {
                   model = mod;
             }
      }
}
```

The model selected is `Galaxy` but I need `Galaxy S3` (i.e, most similar). How can I get `Galaxy S3`.

Should I use `Array.FindAll(target)` method?

**Update:**

By `most similar` I mean the substring (model) that matches the most from string(title)

e.g, in `galaxy Samasung s3 is for sale` the model should be `galaxy s3` (according to above `allModels` array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Most similar?` don't have to be `Search substrings from a string and get a substring that matches the most!` I'll presume you want a longest match...

```
string[] allModels = { "Galaxy", "S3", "Galaxy S3" };
string title = "Samasung galaxy s3 is for sale";

var mod = allModels.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
          .FirstOrDefault(x => title.IndexOf(x,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0);
```

Comment: `allModels` does not contain definition for `Length`. Error

Comment: @IrfanWattoo Copy the code correctly, I don't use *Length* for `allModels` BTW: I run above code before posting :)

Comment: sorry my mistake, what if the title is like `galaxy Samasung s3 is for sale`. the code will not work in this case

Comment: @IrfanWattoo  Correct  it won't. So reread my first sentense and define your similarity function (both are your words) ....

Comment: OK, but you don't say anything about how `galaxy Samasung s3 is for sale` should match `galaxy s3`. What is similarity? As a human we feel it, but you should explain it in algorithmic way.

Comment: The `IndexOf` method of string class is not recognized by `Entity Framework` What could be its alternative?

Comment: You can use `.Contains` method instead of `IndexOf()>=0` , But It doesn't accept `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. So you should convert both strings to lower/upper before using `Contains` BTW: Your question was not related to `Entity Framework`. Please use proper tagging....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find the model containing the most words of the title.

```
var allModelsList = new List<String>(allModels);
var titles = new List<String>(title_array);
allModelsList.OrderByDescending(model => titles.Where(title => title.Equals(model, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: kindly see updated question. What if we have to find `Galaxy S5 Neo` From `Samsung Galaxy Neo S5 for sale`

Comment: ? This would work with my algorithm. In fact the search string would have three matches and would potentially be the first.
The solution marked correct would not even find it...